# Error in setting up NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler ..

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am facing some problems with setting up the uncaught exception handler. Here's what I am doing :

In the app delegate.h:

```
- (void) uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception);
```

In the app delegate.m:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
[FlurryAPI logError:@"Uncaught" message:@"Crash!" exception:exception];
}


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);  // error line
[FlurryAPI startSession:@"API_KEY"];
    ....
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Use of Undeclared Identifier "uncaughtExceptionHandler"
```

Comment: Looks like applicationDidFinishLaunching just can't find the symbol. Try cleaning the project?

Comment: @Patrick : nope doesnt help :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try removing the leading "-" from the method declaration in the app delegate.h. This appears to be a lower-level, C-like function and not an Object-C object-oriented instance method (which is what "-" means in method declaration).

It should look like this:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception);
```